# Leaflet popup does not open on the second click on the marker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, popup, leaflet

I am using leaflet.js to display markers on a OSM map. 
The problem is, that the first time a marker is clicked, the popup opens normally, but on a second click on the same marker the popup does not open anymore.

PS: Anywhere else in the code I close popups (with the `closePopup()` function). In the block below i even commented out the explicit closing of other popups once a marker is clicked.

PPS: My application runs on Ruby on Rails (ruby-1.9.3, Rails 3.2.16), and uses leaflet-rails (0.7.2)

```
bindListeners = function(marker){
    marker.on('click', function(evt) {  

        // resize all markers' icons to default size
        for (i=0; i<markersOfTheMap.length; i++) {
            resizeMarkerIcon(markersOfTheMap[i], false);
        }

        //map.closePopup();

        var infoBoxContent = buildInfoboxHtml(marker);
        
        marker.bindPopup(infoBoxContent, {className: 'click-popup'}, {closeOnClick: false});
        resizeMarkerIcon(marker, true);
        marker.openPopup();

        var popup = marker.getPopup(); // returns marker._popup
        popup._isOpen = true; 
        console.log("is popup open? " +popup._isOpen); // true
        popupsTestArray.push(popup); 
        console.log(popupsTestArray); // popup_isOpen is false...
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue and have ifxed it by the code:

```
marker.on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target._popup == undefined) { // same as e.target.getPopup()
        $.getJSON(url, 
            { entityObject: e.target.options.alt },
            function (infoBoxContent ) {

            // e.target.options.alt contains entity Id
            // from which we will get Infobox window content.
            e.target.bindPopup(infoBoxContent).openPopup();
        });
    }
    else {
        marker.openPopup();
    }
});
```

In the `if` condition we fetch data from server side and bind it to marker popup.
And in Else condition there after same marker is clicked again we will show content from client side.

This code works fine me. If you have any queries then we can discuss here.